# What Are My Options For Porting WebOS SDL + SDL_Mixer Apps to Android

Tags: android, audio, sdl, portability, webos

I have a few published webOS music applications that use SDL for graphics with SDL_Mixer/SDL_Audio for sound.

What would be the best way to make those applications available for Android?  Are the SDL interfaces available or are there similar options?

I only know Python, JavaScript, and C++.  Are there non-Java options or do I need to dig into Java?

Answer (score 3):

You can write C/C++ apps for Android using the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html). It seems someone already figured out how to get [SDL running on it](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/), though if you are using OpenGL ES it would be fairly easy to drop SDL and write directly against GLES (that's what I did for my iOS and Android ports of my webOS apps).

Good luck!